# JComponents not drawn correctly on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, gridbaglayout

I got class Main that extends `JFrame`, and class `Cell` that extends `JComponent`.
`Cell` fills a rectangle (square, sized 50,50) in it's `paintComponent()`.

I'm trying to draw on the `JFrame` 25 `Cell` instances. Their size should be 50,50 (same as the squares they paint), but for some reason, when the program starts, none of them are visible.

However, when I enlarge the window, suddenly the black squares apear as they should.

Why don't they display in the smaller (250,250) window too (the one that starts when the program starts)?

Here's the code:

Class Main:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame
{

    Cell[][] cells = new Cell[5][5];

    public Main(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(250,250);
        setTitle("");
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            gbc.gridy = i+1;
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                gbc.gridx = j+1;
                cells[i][j] = new Cell();
                add(cells[i][j], gbc);
            }
        }

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Main m = new Main();

    }

}
```

Class Cell:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;

public class Cell extends JComponent
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.fillRect(1, 1, 50, 50);

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(50,50);
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to `pack()`; see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why didn't the squares show up the way I did it before? Why did pack() fix this?

Comment: The API addresses this.

Comment: @josh it works because pack uses the preferred size of the content pane to calculate the best size of the frame, that's why you should use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add these to the bottom, right before `setVisbile(true)` it should work

```
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  pack();
  setTitle("");
  setVisible(true);
```

The important part is the `pack()` You shouldn't set the size of the frame. instead pack it so it respects all preferred sizes of components

Tested and it works fine

Comment: GridBagLayout should respect preferred sizes, doesn't it? If so, why do I need to pack?

Comment: But because of that, the fact that you set the size to the frame, doesn't allow enough space for all your components.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the problem was the there wasn't enough room in the JFrame for all the Cells, because I had an Insets set to 5,5,5,5 and then there wasn't enough room?

Now I set the size of the JFrame to 400,400, and with GridBagLayout and without pack() it works fine.

Comment: Yeah and also you may want to draw your rectangles from 0,0 instead of 1,1. It is uneven being painted at 1,1

Comment: `Now I set the size of the JFrame to 400,400, and with GridBagLayout and without pack() it works fine`, No. There is no need to use setSize(). All you need is to use the pack() method and is will set the size of the frame for you.

Answer (score 2):

You get that effect because you use `GridBagLayout`.

You can fix that with help of `GridLayout`, for example add components like next:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5,5,5));

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        cells[i][j] = new Cell();
        add(cells[i][j]);
    }
}
```

[image]

or use `pack()` method as recommended.

Comment: Why does GridBagLayout cause a problem and GridLayout doesn't?

Comment: `GridLayout` makes all components the _same_ size, and it uses the component's _preferred_ size initially.

Comment: `GridLayout` calculates/resizes cells by itself, if size of container lower, as in your case. You can achive that effect with `GridBagLayout` if you use `fill/weightx/weighty` properties of `GridBagConstraints`.